# Formatting a rpm query output with a separator

Tags: python, package, rpm

I am trying to get a list of all packages that are installed on my system. For this I call 'rpm -qai' from within a Python-script where further transformations on the output take place.

I kind of ran into the problem now that the output of above query does not separate the different packages. This looks something like this:

```
$ rpm -qai
Name     : PackageName
Version  : 1.0
...
LastEntry: Something
Name     : NextPackageName
Version  : 1.1
...
```

What I want is something along the line of

```
Name     : PackageName
Version  : 1.0
...
LastEntry: Something
//empty line or some other kind of separator
Name     : NextPackageName
Version  : 1.1
...
```

Since my script reads everything line for line and saves the lines in a dictionary. My workaround as of now checks, if the current line starts with 'Name' and if so, proceeds with appending the dictionary to a list and clearing the dictionary; this step is skipped for the very first line.

This solution is pretty ugly. Unfortunately, a fixed number of lines does not work as not all packages provide the same amount of information.

I also thought about running 'rpm -qai' first, retrieving a list of all package names from this, then iterating over the list while calling 'rpm -qi current_item'. Then one could grab the output from each single query. But since this requires two runs, I deem it unnecessary extra work.

So, does RPM (or some other tool) provide a feature which would allow the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are python bindings for "proper" RPMDB interfacing instead of parsing "`rpm`" output. Think of it as git's porcelain vs plumbing. In fact, `yum` is all python (last time I checked). I think that will be better for you in the long run.

[This documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/ro/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-rpm-programming-python.html) could be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rpm --qf|--queryformat` flag with format string for set the output format.

For example you can use `rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME} %{VERSION}\n"` for get fields interesting for you about every package separated as you want.

Or, just in your case, you can use something like `rpm -qai --qf "\n####\n"`. You will get all fields about every package, but separator setted by you will be between them. Note that Description field may contains multiline text, so it is may be wrong to use \n as separator.

You can read about that in more details using `man rpm`.